# How to append index in the existing tab-delmited file using linux command?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file below and it is tab-delimited.

```
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask
```

I want it to be duplicated in order to make it large file as shown below.

```
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask1
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask2
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask3
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask4
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask5
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask6
```

However, I coded it as below but it didn't work because it the number next to `mask` is always zero even though I incremented it. The my code is shown below.

```
counter=0
for start in {1..5}
do
        awk '{printf("%s \t %s \t %s \t %s \t %s \t %d \n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$counter)}' ./medium/cause1
        let counter=1+$counter
        echo $counter
done
```

Anyway how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{for (i=0;i<3;i++)print $0 i+1}' file
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask1
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask2
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask3
```

Similar, but different result with `cat`:

```
$ cat file file file file | cat -n
 1  TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask
 2  TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask
 3  TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask
 4  TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask
```

You can pass environment variables to awk with a `-v` argument. In your code, `counter` is an awk-variable only and thus initialized with `0` with every invocation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the following awk one-liner:

```
 awk -v times=5 '{while(i<times) print $0(++i)}' file
```

Change the `times` variable to get a different number of lines. You can also pass a shell variable to the awk like:

```
 awk -v times="$VarFromShell" '{.....
```

Comment: I was just adding it to my answer, but got interrupted and now your answer includes it: You should mention that here's also the answer to the question why `$counter` is always zero.

Answer (score 0):

Using `nl` (`man nl`: `nl - number lines of files`) to add the line number and `rev` to add it to the end (will work for the 9 first lines as-is :):

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do rev file ; done |       # 5 copies coming right up - reversed
  nl -w 1 -s "" |                             # add the line number
  rev                                         # re-reverse
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask1
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask2
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask3
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask4
TK              015_LIT NA      CAT     mask5
```